# Unable to get form data after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, console.log

I am trying to send form data after submitting to the `firebase` database using `redux` in my react application, but I am unable to send the state so I tried tracking form data by `console.log` but the form data is empty. I am able to  console log `params` but not `this.state`

Below is the code.

I am using `redux` in this app. `createUser` is my action

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createUser } from "../store/actions/userActions";

class UserForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { form: [], alert: false, alertData: {} };
    this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
  }

  submitMessage = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const params = {
      name: this.inputName.value,
      email: this.inputEmail.value,
      city: this.inputCity.value,
      age: this.inputAge.value
    };
    this.setState({ form: params });
    console.log(params);
    console.log("-----------");
    console.log(this.state);
     this.props.createUser(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div
          className="row"
        >
          User
        </div>
        <div className="container" style={{ padding: `10px 0px` }} />

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-4">
            <h2>Contact Form</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitMessage} ref="contactForm">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  ref={name => (this.inputName = name)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="emai1">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  ref={email => (this.inputEmail = email)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                <select
                  className="form-control"
                  id="city"
                  ref={city => (this.inputCity = city)}
                >
                  <option value="India">India</option>
                  <option value="USA">USA</option>
                  <option value="UK">UK</option>
                  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="age"
                  placeholder="Age"
                  ref={age => (this.inputAge = age)}
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Send
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    createUser: user => dispatch(createUser)
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserForm);
```

Comment: i think you initialize your form state as array and you are setting an object into it.

Comment: callback in setState got me data. Now that you mentioned that I declared array and used object in submit function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is you are missing two things,

1. Set state is async in nature so after set state, you must use call back to access it.
2. You are not passing form data ie. Params to *createUser*

Solution :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createUser } from "../store/actions/userActions";

class UserForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { form: [], alert: false, alertData: {} };
    this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
  }

  submitMessage = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const params = {
      name: this.inputName.value,
      email: this.inputEmail.value,
      city: this.inputCity.value,
      age: this.inputAge.value
    };
    this.setState({ form: params },()=>{
     this.props.createUser(this.state);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div
          className="row"
        >
          User
        </div>
        <div className="container" style={{ padding: `10px 0px` }} />

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-4">
            <h2>Contact Form</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitMessage} ref="contactForm">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  ref={name => (this.inputName = name)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="emai1">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  ref={email => (this.inputEmail = email)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
                <select
                  className="form-control"
                  id="city"
                  ref={city => (this.inputCity = city)}
                >
                  <option value="India">India</option>
                  <option value="USA">USA</option>
                  <option value="UK">UK</option>
                  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="age"
                  placeholder="Age"
                  ref={age => (this.inputAge = age)}
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Send
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    createUser: user => dispatch(createUser(user))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserForm);
```

Comment: This works fine for me but unable to get the sent data into my firebase. As I can see mapDispatchToProps is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Due to `setState` is asynchronous you can access the changed state in a callback which you can pass as a second param to `setState` method. Please read more about [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
  submitMessage = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const params = {
      name: this.inputName.value,
      email: this.inputEmail.value,
      city: this.inputCity.value,
      age: this.inputAge.value
    };
    this.setState({ form: params }, () => {
      console.log(params);
      console.log("-----------");
      console.log(this.state);
      this.props.createUser(this.state);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `createUser` before setState is finished. Why use the state anyway? I would suggest:

```
submitMessage = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const params = {
      name: this.inputName.value,
      email: this.inputEmail.value,
      city: this.inputCity.value,
      age: this.inputAge.value
    };
    this.props.createUser(params);
  };
```